# Too many ni particles in one sentence?

Tags: particle-に

I know, generally, multiples of the same particles in a sentence is okaaay, but perhaps not natural-sounding in everyday conversation? I'm trying to create longer sentences by stringing together clauses:

ninjaっぽいになるために、日光に行った。

Can any particles be dropped here? What should I change? As I understand, へ is used to emphasize direction, but I feel like I should be emphasizing the actual location.

Comment: @Chocolate oh okay, because っぽい is used to describe the becoming, it needs to be conjugated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「～っぽいになる」 is grammatically incorrect. 「～っぽい」 conjugates to 「～っぽく」 in the adverbial/continuative form. cf: 「かわいい」→「かわいく」

日光に行った can be rephrased as 日光へ行った without changing the meaning. (～ヘ行った sounds a tiny little bit more formal to my native ear.)

So you can say:

> Ninjaっぽくなるために、日光に行った。
>   Ninjaっぽくなるために、日光へ行った。

(You could also drop the に in ために, as in 「Ninjaっぽくなるため、日光へ行った。」 but this would sound pretty formal.)

You can also use 「なりたくて」, "wanting/hoping to be~", as in:

> Ninjaっぽくなりたくて、日光に行った。

Comment: Eh that's interesting - why does dropping the に in ために make it more formal?

Comment: I can't say *why*... but 「V+ため～～」 often sounds more formal than 「V+ために～～」 when meaning "in order to~~" (purpose).